# Can a gay/lesbian person get to heaven?

Tags: heaven

Assuming that a gay/lesbian person is genuinely kind, religious, and follows the Ten Commandments. Is it possible for them to go to heaven after death?

And when they go to heaven will they still be gay/lesbians or be man/woman?

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a specific group? As far as I'm aware no major denomination or group even believes it's possible to keep the Ten Commandments or by being "[good enough to go to Heaven](http://christiananswers.net/q-comfort/heaven-goodenough.html)" (hence the need for Christ's substitutionary sacrifice paying the penalty for our sins).  Therefore, the assumption is flawed unless you know of a group that believes this. If you find such a group, we can reasonably answer from that perspective.

Comment: This is a truth question and not a good fit for the SE format.  Also as @DavidStratton pointed out, each denomination may have different answers to this.  Ultimately, I believe it is orthodox for us to not judge.  Therefore, it is not up to us to decide.  Let God figure out who goes to heaven and who doesn't.  All we can do is try our best to follow his guide.

Comment: If the question was changed to "is homosexuality a sin" vs "go to heaven", it would be a doctrine question and not a truth question.  However you can say that sins are forgiven by grace.  From there it's back to denomination doctrine as some believe that forgiveness of sin is forward and backward.  Others believe it's a one time event for all previous sins.  The question need further scope definition.

Comment: If a person where gay then they would not be following Gods law. As to a spirit creatures gender/sexuality I think we are bringing into light only mans perception of such things. What if the angels have no gender or that is are not male or female?

Answer (score 6):

In Rom 1:27, we find that homosexuality is an expression of a world that did not acknowledge God as the Creator to be worshiped. But the blood of Jesus cleanses us from all sin, including the sins of the homosexual, when we trust in Him for salvation.

So what is a redeemed homosexual to do? The same as a redeemed thief or adulterer -- sin no more. Turn away from living for the flesh to living for God (Romans 6). Paul gives us a warning that if we willfully pursue the flesh, such "will not inherit the kingdom" (1 Cor. 6:9-10).

According to Benware's book, *The Believer's Payday,* inheriting the kingdom means being rewarded with riches and honor for one's good works. So a redeemed homosexual, continuing in his homosexual practices, may make it to heaven, but will appear before the judgment without inheriting the kingdom, in shame and not joy (1 John 2:28-29).

So 2 Peter 1:5-11 encourages us to grow in godliness rather than continue in the flesh in order to prove that we are worthy of the special privileges of those who inherit the kingdom.

Answer (score 2):

Your question indicates that you are unaware of the fundamentals of Christianity:  God’s children place their faith in God’s love for them, not because His children are lovable but because it is God’s nature to love.  Jesus is God’s love made manifest (grace).

> Ephesians 2:8 for by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God

Faith in God’s love, wants what God wants for His children in this life.  God has provided His children with the Holy Sprit in order for His will to be made manifest in their lives.  This outcome determines how much of their life will stand the test of fire.

> 1 Corinthians 3:13,14 Every man's work shall be made manifest: for the day shall declare it, because it shall be revealed by fire; and the fire shall try every man's work of what sort it is. If any man's work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward

So can a gay person get to Heaven, the answer is yes, Jesus died on the cross in order that sinners can get to Heaven.  However, sinners will not enter Heaven, only those that have been born anew and washed with the blood of Jesus.  The new birth comes with a new identity, we become God’s children those “born of the Holy Spirit” and as a result our old sinful identities are no longer relevant.

A Christian is one that has the ability through the presence of the Holy Spirit to bear Jesus Christ out in their life, thus the works that will stand the test of fire.

Why would one stand before God ignoring His new identity in favor of a sexual identity?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot keep the 7th Commandment and be a homosexual, that is homosexuality is breaking the 7th commandment, "Thou shalt not commit adultery." The Bible expounds on the matter saying that marriage is between a man and a woman, and God denounces homosexuality as an abomination.

> If a man has sexual relations with a man as one does with a woman,
>   both of them have done what is detestable. They are to be put to
>   death; their blood will be on their own heads.
>
> Leviticus 20:13
>
> Or do you not know that wrongdoers will not inherit the kingdom of
>   God? Do not be deceived: Neither the sexually immoral nor idolaters
>   nor adulterers nor men who have sex with men nor thieves nor the
>   greedy nor drunkards nor slanderers nor swindlers will inherit the
>   kingdom of God.
>
> 1 Corinthians 6:9-10

What we must not forget though is that WE HAVE ALL SINNED. To God homosexuality, theft, murder, deceit, is a sin and you cannot go to heaven if you have done any of these. That is why Jesus came along.

If I were to murder a child, would it be fair if a judge acquitted me of my crime? No, it would be a terrible injustice to the parents and to society if I'm still walking free. God is just and any crime, or sin, cannot be pardoned just because I say I'm sorry. I need to pay for my crime. The payment for any sin is death. So are we doomed to die?

No, Jesus paid for my sins at the cross. He also paid for the sin of homosexuality, and all the other sins of every person. But because of this am I free to murder again? God forbid! This is what repentance is about.

The word repentance means a turning away from sin. If we are to be forgiven we need to turn away from our sin and follow Jesus. Like Jesus said to the woman.

> ...And Jesus said unto her, Neither do I condemn thee: go, and sin no
>   more.
>
> John 8:11

Many people have been taught that trying to keep God's Law is legalism and to try to follow it is impossible, but this cannot be further from the truth. Jesus said to the multitude in His sermon on the Mount:

> Be ye therefore perfect, even as your Father which is in heaven is
>   perfect.
>
> Matthew 5:48

Was Jesus lying? No, we can do it, through Christ who strengthens us! We cannot be saved by the Law, because that is not its purpose. We have the blood of Jesus for that. The Law shows us where we are at fault. If we do break the Law again, we are no longer under grace and are in need of Jesus' salvation again.

Going back to the above text, there was a part I didn't include on purpose.

> Or do you not know that wrongdoers will not inherit the kingdom of
>   God? Do not be deceived: Neither the sexually immoral nor idolaters
>   nor adulterers nor men who have sex with men nor thieves nor the
>   greedy nor drunkards nor slanderers nor swindlers will inherit the
>   kingdom of God. **And that is what some of you WERE. But you were
>   washed, you were sanctified, you were justified in the name of the
>   Lord Jesus Christ and by the Spirit of our God.**
>
> 1 Corinthians 6:9-11

The grace of Christ is sufficient for all sinners who have broken God's perfect Law.

In conclusion a person that is gay/lesbian CANNOT inherit the Kingdom of God, just like a murderer cannot inherit the Kingdom of God, because they are sinners. A sinner has broken the 10 Commandments and so cannot keep them. Can they go to heaven? No. Only if they repent and accept Jesus Christ as their Savior will they go into heaven, but if this is the case, they are NO LONGER Gay or lesbian or murderer. They are no longer a sinner because Jesus has washed their sin.

Comment: So the short answer was no? Thanks for answering

Comment: @FFCoder Correct. A person that is still living in sin, whether homosexuality or another, will not inherit the Kingdom of Heaven.

Comment: @jlaverde, So you believe that one has to be perfect or perfectly repented in order to enter God's Kingdom? Then what role does faith in God's grace play?

Comment: @Rick At conversion. Grace is for sinners, which we all are so we all need it. This is when, by His grace, we are washed by Him. Afterwards, He sanctifies us; meaning He sets us apart for a Holy purpose. Then we are justified before God and the cosmos (men and angels). But if I fall into sin once again, I would need grace, once again. A simple illustration. You are stopped by a police officer for speeding; you have broken the law. He lets you off with a warning, he gives you grace. Do you go back to speeding? No. Out of respect and gratefulness to the officer you do not break the law anymore.

Comment: @jlaverde, and you are commended?

Comment: @Rick Not at all. I wouldn't get commended for keeping the speed limit, just as I shouldn't be commended for keeping the Law. It is not because I will get something that I keep the Law, but instead because I love Jesus and I know what a terrible price He paid for my sin. That is true repentance. The apostles, John the Baptist, and Jesus Himself called people to true repentance, a turning away and forsaking of sin. Of course, all this is a process, it doesn't happen overnight. We strive for perfection until you reach it.

Comment: "To him who overcomes I will grant to sit with Me on My throne, as I also overcame and sat down with My Father on His throne." Rev. 3:21

Comment: @jlaverde, Just checking?

Answer (score 0):

The church does not condem Gay/Lesbian people but homosexual acts.This is only in the case that the said homosexual person feel repentant for his acts. if he feels like he has sinned and repents for then he/she may go to heaven provided the remaining part of his/her life is proper.
 as for the question of will the still be a man or a woman.I think we are souls and not classfied under gender in heaven

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible, because the person you described is not following the Ten Commandments. No one is. Romans 3:23:

> for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God,

Comment: On the face of it, it appears that you are saying that no-one at all will reach heaven.

Comment: I think he's pointing out the glaring flaw in FFCoder's assumption.  This s the start of a really good answer, if it were to go on to explain the flaw, and perhaps explore whether Christ's sacrifice covers homosexuality... It would be difficult to scope, however, given the broad nature of the question.

Comment: It's a good thing that our sins have been forgiven.